# rename files from old to new as listed in csv

Tags: excel, file, rename, names

I have an excel/CSV file with two columns. The first is the name of the file and the 2nd column is what I want it named to.  the Excel/CSV file and PDFs are in same folder

How can I do this with the least programming. I am no coder.

example

```
Column 1      Column 2
old1           New 1
old2           New 2
odl3           New 3
```

I can always append the file path in front of the name in excel if that makes it easier

Thanks

Comment: in vba you can use `Name old1 as New 1`. you'll need the full path and a `For Loop` to run through the rows.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Can you expand on that? I've never seen `Name [] as New []` that I recall. Edit: Ah, nevermind. I actually have used that in a macro I have...just forgot about it! I'd look in to this OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the Path where the Files are located as well as the name with extensions. Then you could end up doing something like this in VBA.

```
Sub NameFiles()
Dim Path = "c:\temp\" 'keep the backslash at the end
dim a as range
dim x as long
x = 2
For each a in Range("a2:a4") 
OldName = a.value 'make sure your column contains name with file extension.
NewName = cells(x,2).value 'make sure your new column has extensions also
Name Path & OldName As Path & NewName
x = x + 1
next a
End Sub
```